# In a Measure Space show $ \mu(A) + \mu(B)= \mu(A \cup B)+\mu(A \cap B) $

Tags: measure-theory

suppose $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is a measuer space and $A,B\in\mathcal{A}$
prove that
$$  \mu(A) + \mu(B)= \mu(A \cup B)+\mu(A \cap B) $$

---

Here, $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma $- algebra on a set $X$,  is a collection, denoted $\mathcal{A}$, of a subset $X$ such that

1. $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$
2. If $A \in \mathcal{A}$ then $A^c = X \setminus A \in \mathcal{A}$
3. If $\{ A_i : i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is countable family set mutually disjoint in $\mathcal{A}$ then $\cup^{\infty}_{i=1} A_i \in \mathcal{A}$

   ---

**Attempt**

Let $C=A-B$ and $D=B-A$ so $C \cup B=A \cup D=A \cup B$ and $C \subset A$ and $D \subset B$ (*Drew diagramns on my own*)

$$\begin{aligned}
\mu(A \cup B) + \mu(A \cap B) &=\mu(C \cup B)+\mu(A \cap B) 
\\ &= \mu(C)+\mu(B)+\mu(A \cap B) 
\\ &=\mu(B)+\mu(C \cup (A\cap B))
\\ &= \mu(B)+\mu((C \cup A)\cap (C \cup B))
\\ &= \mu(B)+\mu(A \cap (A \cup D))
\\ & = \text{more steps?? Right direction?}
\\ &=\mu(A)+\mu(B)
\end{aligned} $$

Comment: $(A \cap (A \cup D) ) = A$ as $A \subset A \cup D$.  Just this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is just a matter of writing $A\cup B$ as a well-chosen union of disjoint sets:
$A\cup B=(A\setminus (A\cap B))\cup(B\setminus(A\cap B))\cup(A\cap B)$ where the sets on the RHS are disjoint. Therefore,
$$\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A\setminus (A\cap B))+\mu(B\setminus(A\cap B))+\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A)-\mu(A\cap B)+\mu(B)-\mu(A\cap B)+\mu(A\cap B)$$
which simplifies to the desired equality.